# Reflect vector against normal

Tags: java, 2d, game-physics

I've been trying to calculate a reflection velocity of a particle (Circle2D) against a platform's normal vector.

```
Vector2D reflect(Vector2D vector, Vector2D normal) {
    double velocityDotProduct = Vector2D.dot(normal, vector);
    Vector2D reflectVector = new Vector2D(vector.getX() - 2 * velocityDotProduct * normal.getX(), vector.getY() - 2 * velocityDotProduct * normal.getY());
    return reflectVector;
}
```

This is returning the correct x velocity but is giving a tiny y velocity.

```
Before: x=5.0 y=20.39999999999999
After: x=5.000000009209657 y=-1.5040509959999993E8
```

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: So..uuh, what is your actual question then?

Comment: Show us both input parameters. Just because something is called `normal` doesn't mean it has a length of 1.

Comment: Just realised that I wasn't taking the perpendicular vector of the platform properly. Therefore it was working perfectly but just with the wrong vector to reflect against.

Comment: That y component `-1.50e8` is HUGE. Did you normalize the normal?